# Rails ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError when using link_to for update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, strong-parameters

I have been trying to create a link to update the status(which is an enum) of a person in my rails app but I keep on getting the following error when I run it.

> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

this is the link that I am trying to use

```
 <%= link_to 'Present', person_path(person, person: {status: :present}), method: :put %>
```

and the strong parameters are as follows

```
params.require(:person).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :data, :status)
```

here is the update method from my controller

```
      def update
    @person = Person.find params[:id]
    if @person.update_attributes params[:person]
      format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was shot and stabbed' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @person }
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      if @person.update(person_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @person }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

How do I create a simple link to update the status of the person without getting the ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError error?

Comment: As you are passing entire person object,i assume all the attributes of Person Model are required in controller...

Comment: can you post your update method from the controller?

Comment: just added it, thanks